# Getting Fatal error when running ZF2 project on php 7.1.1 Zend\Stdlib\PriorityQueue contains 1 abstract method

Tags: zend-framework2, php-7

I'm getting the following Fatal error when running a ZendFramework2 project on PHP 7.1.1.

The error is:

> Fatal error: Class Zend\Stdlib\PriorityQueue contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Serializable::unserialize) in F:\xampp\htdocs\MyZF2Site\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Stdlib\PriorityQueue.php on line 28

What could be the sulution?

Comment: If I run the same project on PHP 7.0 then that fatal error disappeared. Should not PHP 7.1.1 be backward compatible?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Already I solved it.

1. PHP 7.1.9
   Fatal error: Class Zend\Stdlib\PriorityQueue contains 5 abstract methods...
2. Change PHP 7.0.23. To change is very easy for me because I use wampserver.
   It's work 0k ¡
3. Againg to change to PHP 7.1.9.
   It worked 0k forever. Why?¡¡  I don't know. I think it is issue cache.

slds

Answer (score 0):

Almost always there are some backwards incompatible changes, in this case you can check out those changes here http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php.

Here http://php.net/manual/en/appendices.php you can see changes in previous versions.

You did not say which exactly version of ZF2 you use.

Comment: Hi Tomm, Thanks for you reply. Regarding my zend version: I've been using version 2.3.2. Thanks